# Angular i18n: Forward translation string to own component

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

I have an own component which looks simplified like:

```
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>{{myLabel}}</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi">
  </mat-form-field>
```

and in the `ts` code something like

```
 @Input() myLabel:string;
```

When I now want to include it in my component I use for the HTML part:

```
 <my-component [label]="'Favorite food'"></my-component>
```

My question: How to specify the content of `label` in a way that it will translated as well? Does it work with `i18n-label`??? Or do I need something additional in the component?